# Hardware of amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: result]

Output result of the circuit

[image: circuit construction]
[image: ideal result]

I have connected the circuit in hardware, but how come the output is like this?

[image: input result after connected to opamp]

Comment: You have a very high-performance opamp in a very low-performance breadboard. You need to tighten up your circuit layout, use much shorter wires, add power supply bypass caps, etc.

Comment: How did you come up with the 8.2 pF value for those power supply bypass capacitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts: -

- The recommended supply voltage range is up to +/-15V not 16 volts as you have in your circuit
- 8.2pF capacitors are probably totally ineffective as supply de-couplers - try 100nF
- Breadboards are probably not the best way of connecting the device up and can cause large instabilities.
- What is your shut-down pin connected to?
- All the specs on the device imply a load connected to the output of about a maximum of 1k. Your load is the feedback resistor of 2k8 so this may also be a problem. Try lowering it or put a load resistor of (say) 220R on the output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i didnt connect the shut down pin,will it have pose a problem?....as I need a gain 28, that why I use 28k..okay, I try to lower my resistor..and then this opamp is video opamp,will it pose any problem?

Comment: If you didn't connect the shut down pin maybe it'll be ok but check the data sheet to be sure. If you can't lower the 2800 ohms too much then put a load on the output of maybe 220R.

Comment: actually what is the benefit of putting 220 R in the output?

Comment: The data sheet does not appear to recommend running the op-amp without at least 1k ohm load on the output - read my final point in my answer.

Comment: alright, thanks..tomorrow i will try to connect with 1k load ....

Comment: ,it solved my problem, I get the output waveform..but have a problem regarding the amplitude of input, before connected to the amplifier,my input value is 1.1Vpp,after connected to non-inverting opamp, then I measure again the amplitude of input, it become 560mV,so why the amplitude will decreased?

Comment: The input impedance of your circuit is 100 ohms. Have you factored this into your calculations. Try separately connecting a load of 100 ohms to your input signal and seeing what happens to it.

Comment: alright, do this called as loading effect? and then I have a question "no rail to rail" meaning that my curcuit output amplitude dynamic range is not equal to 30V ?for +15V and -15V.

Comment: It's called loading effect yes. It can mean that inputs are not rail to rail too but ya got the basic concept.

Comment: erm, my maximun rail to rail is 15Vpp only?as after 15Vpp it will clip the signal.and for the result I have added, is it due by noise?